# Is there a way to take down a Bigtable instance (or a cluster) without deleting it, kinda chaos testing

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable, chaos

Similar how we do chaos testing, I want a Bigtable instance (or a cluster) to be down. Like it goes down in any outage/catastrophic event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to take down a Bigtbale instance without deleting, unfortunately. You could use [Backups](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/backups) for your testing:

> Bigtable backups let you save a copy of a table's schema and data,
> then restore from the backup to a new table at a later time.

There is also a [Bigtable emulator](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/emulator) which can be used for application testing.

I'd also like to encourage your to create a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187206&template=0) for Google to consider this feature.